# HP Proliant DL180se G6 Not booting up

Tags: windows, hardware, hp, boot

Recently, I found one of the fan in my HP Proliant DL180se G6 server went faulty and i replaced it with a new one along with a new ram to add more memory to it.

However, when I press the boot button at the front (as well as in IPMI), the fans spin up to maximum speed as normal, and then everything shutdown again right after 1 second.

I checked through the HP Light-out (IPMI) panel, and i didn't found any thing goes wrong. So, I checked through the log , and it displays something like this:

[image: screenshot of log]

I seems like it is having the issue with the power, but i am not sure. Can anyone help me out on this one?